# SQL Query Optimisation (Direction of Condition Evaluation)

Tags: sql, query-optimization

Let's say I have a dictionary of 26000 words, 1000 words per letter of the alphabet.
If I want to find all the words that have an 'e' in them, I write:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM dict 
 WHERE word LIKE '%e%';
```

If I wanted to reduce that to only the words beginning with 'a' I could change the like condition or I could do this:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM dict 
 WHERE word LIKE '%e%' 
   AND id < 1000;
```

Lots of words have the letter 'e' in them and so would return true only to fail the second requirement if the conditions are evaluated left to right but I would expect faster results if the condition is evaluated from right to left.

My question is, would it be better to have the `id < 1000` as the first or second condition or does this depend on the type of database.

Comment: Don't put brackets/parenthesis on LIKE clauses -- they're for order of operations only.  And use single quotes for string comparisons in SQL, not double quotes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The location of the condition is irrelevant, the same number of scans (if applicable) will be required. They are not parsed in order -- the optimizer determines what is applied, and when, based on table statistics and indexes (if any exist). Those statistics change, and can become out of date (which is why maintenance is important).

Comment: Then surely a simple boolean check `id < 1000` will be faster than a `like ("%e%")` query which would not be done if the id comparison is performed first (unless they're evaluated in separate threads).

Comment: The execution plan will be identical regardless of whether the id check is performed first or last

Comment: so which will be evaluated first then? Since surely if the first condition evaluated fails the second would not be evaluated...

Comment: @j3frea: The optimizer determines what is applied, and when, based on table statistics and indexes (if any exist).  Those statistics change, and can become out of date (which is why maintenance is important).  There is no more definitive answer to your question than that.

Comment: Thanks OMG Ponies: "optimizer determines"

Comment: sorry the answer is not correct, it could make a difference, the only real way to know is to explain plan the query.

Answer (score 1):

It would be bad to assume `id < 1000` to be the equivalent of

`SELECT * FROM dict WHERE word LIKE'a%'`.

If you designed your database this way it would violate First Normal form. [1NF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form), Specifically: There's no top-to-bottom ordering to the rows.
Technically there isn't a way to ensure this ordering is valid, especially if you wanted to add a word starting with 'A' after you setup your initial state.

Comment: +1 Doing this also prevents you from ever being able to add new rows.

Comment: okay but the question is regarding order of condition evaluation.

Comment: The answer is your second condition is invalid and shouldn't be used.  Try a better example that doesn't violate the core of Relational Database design.

Comment: That's just a stupid answer dude. I've simplified my question because in reality I have something more complex but the complexities are irrelevant. What is relevant is the order of condition evaluation. What if one of my columns were a boolean and I needed it to be a particular value. Drop the id condition and say `proper_noun=TRUE`. It's the same question.

Comment: In that case I'd say you need to identify what RDBMS you are using since they evaluate and execute queries differently.  Reading the answers ChrisBint has the best one so far.  I'm simply telling you your original example is flawed and you should update it to 'proper_noun=TRUE'.  Before you do that nobody should tell you otherwise how it will be evaluated.

Comment: I considered doing that when two answers came that weren't relevant but the fact that other responses have taken the question as it now stands into account makes it silly to change at this point.

Answer (score 0):

One of the key design principles of modern relational database management systems is that you, the user, have no true control or say over how the data is actually being stored on the hard drive by the RDBMS. This means that you cannot assume that the data is (a) stored in alphabetical order on the drive, or (b) that when you retrieve the data, it will be retrieved in alphabetical order. The only way to be absolutely 100% sure that you are getting the data you want is to spell out the way you want it, and anything else is an assumption that some day may blow up in your face.

Why does this matter? Because your query assumes that the data you'll be getting will be in alphabetical order, starting with "A" and going up. (And that assumes consistent case--what about "A" vs "a"? Anything with leading spaces or numbers? Different systems handle different data differently...) Fixing this is simple enough, add an `ORDER BY` clause, such as:

```
select * from dict where word like ("%e%") and id < 1000 order by word;
```

Of course, if you have more than 1000 words beginning with "A" and containing "e", you're in trouble... and if you have less than 1000, you end up with a bunch of "B" words. Try something like:

```
select * from dict where left(word. 1) = "A" and word like ("%e%");
```

Depending on your RDBMS and any indexing you have on the table, the system could first identify all "A" words, and then run the "contains *e*" check on only them.

Comment: as I said to N. Warfield, my actual question is regarding optimisation based on the order of condition evaluation.

Answer (score 0):

Try switching your where clause conditions around and then compare the execution plans.

This will show you the difference, if any (I would guess they will be identical, in this case)

The bottom line is, most of the time it makes no difference.
However it can change the execution plan.

Comment: According to OMG Ponies, "The optimizer determines what is applied, and when, based on table statistics and indexes (if any exist)." so, in other words, "Order of WHERE clauses is irrelevant to performance". Thanks

Comment: that may or may not be true, the explain plan will show you the answer.

Comment: here's some links that suggest it does matter http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/transactsql/thread/2d365b19-885a-4632-9c52-bd99969dfa89

http://www.dba-oracle.com/Oracle_tips_sql_predicate_order.htm

Comment: even Tom Kyte will not guarantee a change in the order of the predicates will generate identical plans see http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1857060700346051220